# 579085261 is CRAZY, 725582 is GOLF, 10757494 is ...?

Tags: code-golf, string, primes, cipher

Your task is to translate a [103-smooth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) into an English word, using the method described below.

### How?

1. Generate the list of prime factors (with repetition) of the input number.
2. Sort the list:

   - If **2** is not one of the prime factors, sort the list in ascending order.
   - If **2** is one of the prime factors, remove it from the list and sort the remaining factors in descending order.
3. Translate each factor into a letter, using the following table:

   ```
    3 = S   13 = L   29 = X   43 = O   61 = Z   79 = H  101 = K  
    5 = P   17 = Q   31 = N   47 = R   67 = T   83 = V  103 = Y  
    7 = M   19 = U   37 = C   53 = A   71 = E   89 = D  
   11 = F   23 = I   41 = W   59 = G   73 = J   97 = B
   ```

*<sub>**Note**: This table was built empirically to maximize the number of possible words. For the curious, [here is a list of 2,187 words](https://pastebin.com/7dBFbt5b) that can be encoded that way (may include rude language). It's definitely not guaranteed to be optimal, but it's good enough for this challenge.</sub>*

### Examples

**Example 1: 579085261** (ascending order)

1. The prime factors are **[ 37, 47, 53, 61, 103 ]**.
2. **2** is not a prime factor, so we keep the list sorted in ascending order.
3. 37 = C, 47 = R, etc. The output is "CRAZY".

**Example 2: 725582** (descending order)

1. The prime factors are **[ 2, 11, 13, 43, 59 ]**.
2. **2** is a prime factor, so we remove it and sort the list in descending order, which gives:
   **[ 59, 43, 13, 11 ]**.
3. 59 = G, 43 = O, etc. The output is "GOLF".

**Example 3: 10757494** (with a repeated factor)

1. The prime factors are **[ 2, 11, 71, 71, 97 ]**.
2. **2** is a prime factor, so we remove it and sort the list in descending order, which gives:
   **[ 97, 71, 71, 11 ]**.
3. 97 = B, 71 = E, 11 = F. The output is "BEEF".

### Clarifications and rules

- The input number is guaranteed to be 103-smooth and divisible by 2 at most once.
- By definition, a smooth-number is a *positive integer*.
- Input and output can be handled in any reasonable format. The output can be in lowercase or uppercase. Trailing whitespace is acceptable. Leading whitespace is not.
- If your program/function can't support large inputs, please specify it in your answer.
- This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
34874          --> ARM
483254         --> BAR
353722         --> EAR
494302         --> EGG
39061          --> FAT
6479           --> FUN
60421          --> ICE
54166          --> JAM
48911474       --> BETA
2510942        --> BOOM
2303854        --> DOOM
844261         --> FIRE
1606801        --> MAZE
1110085        --> PAGE
5212974        --> BALLS
67892046       --> BEANS
885396199      --> CREEK
67401037       --> FUNKY
27762173       --> QUICK
1238440506     --> ARROWS
33045832681    --> CRAGGY
1362714005     --> PIRATE
137302698      --> TROLLS
358310128062   --> BEGGARS
40255151586    --> DETAILS
164633248153   --> FIXATED
621172442227   --> UNRATED
2467812606     --> VACUUMS
86385078330    --> GROWNUPS
26607531423091 --> UNWORTHY
```

Comment: Ohhh crap... 05AB1E cache hit when using `Ò` on `579085261`, feel like <s>Emigna</s> Adnan has already started.

Comment: You could've allowed multiple factors of 2, then made it so that increasing the number of factors changes the index at which the reversal starts.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, there are many possible variants. My initial idea was to encode _any_ word by working on groups of letters.

Comment: The test cases on this challenge remind be of those "discover your X name" things on Facebook. Find the title of the movie you're in! Step one, choose your favorite prime number `<=103`... your result is `PIRATE MAZE`, or `DOOM VACUUMS`...

Comment: I'm curious as to how you assigned each number to a letter. Was it random, or did you have a specific pattern to it?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp It was first randomly shuffled and tested against a dictionary of ~106K words, up to 11 letters (the file is on my HD for a long time -- I think it was originally extracted from the [TWL](http://bit.ly/2qdAKIW)). Then I forced 'S' to be either first or last to maximize plural words and tried a couple of individual letter exchanges on a good combination (recursively). Finally, I lost patience and wrote the challenge. :-) Actually, before all of this, I tried to take [Letter Counts by Position Within Word](http://norvig.com/mayzner.html) into account but it wasn't all that great.

Comment: What's the rule on trailing whitespace?

Comment: @ValueInk Updated. Trailing whitespace is allowed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
ÆEµØA“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?xḊṚḢ}¡
```

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#FU89SgNREL5KelPM/8yrxMJDeBMbIQgqpLGwScRmra0EYRPEYoMBj/H2IusMD@aHN9/fcnq8nr5Ou6t58zYN3MeHPn5e9MPP3/c09OPzed@P2/Nu3ux/Xy5v@7jth9c@vt9Nw3J6mu8/bpaFJVzWKwkmzc7KTpR7E4bs3MBwvTLxlhWEclFBs4I0RCkwKUKTvCYGjqIJESocGlhADYgAoQkmpFYg82gEkkQRys2wlYILILAnlbsROieUOOlAIU@ZQTStWhQnGzkKgNbs6ddaVIRgBKQAqyBAqpgvrOyIMZMEahInPzqlU6ISlHSEZCUTljHAI@XywwxcGSXTNfwH)

#### Background

```
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’
```

is a numeric literal. The characters between the quotes are replaced with their 1-based indices in the [Jelly code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), and the resulting array is interpreted as a base-250 number. This yields the integer **c := 288824892868083015619552399**.

#### How it works

```
ÆEµØA“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?xḊṚḢ}¡  Main link. Argument: n

ÆE                           Yield the exponents of n's prime factorization, with.
                             zeroes. This yields an array A.
  µ                          Begin a new monadic chain with argument A.
   ØA                        Set the return value to “ABC...XYZ”.
     “¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?        Select the c-th permutation of the alphabet, yielding
                             s := “SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY”.
                      Ḋ      Dequeue; yield A without its first element, stripping
                             the exponent of 2.
                     x       Repeat the k-th letter of s r times, where r is the
                             exponent of the k-th odd prime number.
                          ¡  Combine the two links to the left into a quicklink:
                        Ḣ}     - Apply head to the right argument (A), yielding the
                                 exponent of 2. Since n is at most divisible by the
                                 first power of 2, this yields 1 for even numbers
                                 and 0 for odd ones. Call the link to the left that
                                 many times on the previous return value.
                       Ṛ       - Reverse the string to the left.
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 bytes

```
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?ØA1;;⁶
×107ÆE¢×UḢ¡t⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AWkAlv//4oCcwqEz4biF4biyK@G5vsm8wqHhuo/GmeG6isaY4oCZxZM/w5hBMTs74oG2CsOXMTA3w4ZFwqLDl1XhuKLCoXTigbb/w4figqxL//9bNTc5MDg1MjYxLDcyNTU4MiwxMDc1NzQ5NF0)

### Explanation

**Helper constant `1£`** (produces `“SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY ”` with a 1 prepended)

```
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?ØA1;;⁶
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’          288824892868083015619552399 (compressed representation)
              œ?ØA      th permutation of the alphabet
                  1;    prepend 1
                    ;⁶  append a space
```

**Main program**

```
×107ÆE¢×UḢ¡t⁶
×107           Multiply {the input} by 107
    ÆE         Convert to a list of frequencies for each factor
      ¢×       {Vectorized} multiply by the return value of 1£
        UḢ¡    Delete the first value, reverse the list that many times
           t⁶  Delete trailing/leading space
```

I have a feeling that my compression of the list easily beats the other Jelly answer, but that my algorithm for using it could be a lot more efficient. Maybe I'll try to combine them.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes, inspired by @Leakynun's answer

```
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?ØA⁷;
ÆfÆCị¢U⁸¡U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AWgAl///4oCcwqEz4biF4biyK@G5vsm8wqHhuo/GmeG6isaY4oCZxZM/w5hB4oG3OwrDhmbDhkPhu4vColXigbjhuILCpMKhVf/Dh@KCrEv//1s1NzkwODUyNjEsNzI1NTgyLDEwNzU3NDk0XQ) (slightly modified to run a lot faster)

Is inconsistent in whether it prints a trailing newline (but PPCG normally allows answers either with or without a trailing newline, so I guess this works too?). Is *very* slow (O(*n*) where *n* is the input, and those numbers aren't exactly small…)

### Explanation

**Helper constant `1£`** (produces `“¶SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY”`, where `¶` is newline)

```
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?ØA⁷;
“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’          288824892868083015619552399 (compressed representation)
              œ?ØA      th permutation of the alphabet
                  ⁷;    prepend newline
```

**Main program**

```
ÆfÆCị¢U⁸¡U
Æf          Produce list of prime factors (repeating repeated factors)
  ÆC        Map the nth prime to n
    ị¢      Index into the output of 1£
      U     Reverse
        ¡   a number of times
       ⁸    equal to the input
         U  Reverse again
```

Comment: That's a very nice way to store a permutation of the alphabet...

Comment: Ah you have used my permutation atom too :D

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
ÒW<iR¨}26LØR•6Ê2"£´õþÕàçŸôëÂÛ*™•36BS:J
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AUUAuv//w5JXPGlSwqh9MjZMw5hS4oCiNsOKMiLCo8K0w7XDvsOVw6DDp8W4w7TDq8OCw5sq4oSi4oCiMzZCUzpK//83MjU1ODI)

Comment: I knew it was one of you hahaha. *scrapes halfway finished answer into the garbage*

Comment: @carusocomputing the cache hits can bring up some time pressure haha

Comment: `Ø` was the part of this that beat mine by 20 bytes anyway :P.

Comment: I think you can do [Ò26ÝØR•1Sî?¾±=&ÔìÍècS¦ÁÜ7d•36BS:Já¹GR](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AUEAvv//w5IyNsOdw5hS4oCiMVPDrj/CvsKxPSbDlMOsw43DqGNTwqbDgcOcN2TigKIzNkJTOkrDocK5R1L//zcyNTU4Mg) for 37.

Comment: @Emigna Yeah, but the only problem is that it would take forever for the bigger test cases so I'm probably not going to include that version, but thanks anyway!

Comment: It's not very efficient no ;)

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>139</s> <s>138</s> <s>134</s> <s>125</s> <s>120</s> 115+7 = <s>146</s> <s>145</s> <s>141</s> <s>132</s> <s>127</s> 122 bytes

Uses the `-rprime` flag for +7 bytes.

-1 byte from @daniero. -4 bytes by remembering that I can just do a regular divisibility check instead of checking the prime division for the existence of `2`.

-9 bytes from @mbomb007's Python solution reminding me of a shorter way to retrieve the matching letter.

-5 bytes because trailing whitespace is now allowed.

-5 bytes from discovering `Enumerable#find_index`

```ruby
->n{x=Prime.prime_division n;x.reverse!if n%2<1;x.map{|i,c|" SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY"[Prime.find_index i]*c}*''}
```

[Try it online! (all test cases)](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#JY9tT1QxEIW/z6@4vBiQuJt563QaxURFAUVEUVDRbHC5mzSBy@YukCXAb19HSdO0OT1zztOVpf76z20z6Kd9vWibQQcw2fy1GLzs7uabB/@04f@X0Vm9qbN62TXd8/mwb2/aftYu1UnTPeEXFNLF6fTuvj4b3y83hwcf3@19/rb7ff/N8acvr7Z/fn37fudo6/WHH8snj5GT2p2NYrfzpv7eGD9srK09LKbXV7NmMhyfnp@vr46GV5ej@nQh6llBXTgpSJLMDFpUkMFQmSApmYEUNALTXMJbiDSGOBEWZWBB8Zh2VQ4TGZpjnESIniAxcQm7ZS@MauCepBiVEpIioWTgnI0pCxBLxGDCqBTUFFzmkSXGmRQxxTUHnBUPWhdCYkcLZuSUKJZbEKiJsDolgcilzIHGHD0aFMRBCG4BjdmjBtgMcxLS@Eqhvw)

#### Explanation

```ruby
->n{                                   # Anonymous procedure with one argument n
    x=Prime.prime_division n;          # Get prime factorization of n, sorted
                                       # p0^e0 * p1^e1 ... -> [[p0,e0],[p1,e1],...]
    x.reverse!if n%2<1;                # Reverse if divisible by 2
    x.map{|i,c|                        # For each prime/exponent pair:
        " SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY"[ # Get corresponding character by obtaining:
            Prime.find_index i]        # Determine index of the current prime
                               *c      # Repeat the letter by the supplied exponent
                                 }*''} # Join all letter sequences together
```

Comment: Nice one. You can remove the space between `zip` and `"`

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>220</s> 217 bytes

```python
n=input()
i=1
L=[]
exec'i+=1;c=0\nwhile n%i<1:c+=1;n/=i\nif c:L+=[i]*c\n'*n
T='SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY'
print''.join(T[[p for p in range(3,104)if all(p%k for k in range(2,p))].index(q)]for q in[L,L[:0:-1]][L[0]<3])
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RczLTgIxFIDhfZ@iG9IWBpwCwTjQhaCiWLzAcNFOF6QWPTI5lAlE3n4EN27/L/lLVIDhsOeCgJJEK2OJP3rHoKZk16k4w58vyD3FCvRk4s4VLxRkCGvqEl1TBmzVZciqSFLFpi/jO/06e1g@DRbPk@vhe3o7up/f9B/fGAkF4J6xxvcWkKfGBLreFjRQQFqs8NPzViTjtjiNV3nOQ2Xz55t/b0ZBCNsA/PBHvhP2zLsTGx1pk8RJXVprtIltr2VFWXbal1e/) - *only runs the smallest test case without running out of memory*

#### Ungolfed:

This version doesn't use `exec`, so you can actually test all of the test cases without running out of memory.

```python
n=input()
i=1
L=[]
while~-n:
 i+=1;c=0
 while n%i<1:c+=1;n/=i
 if c:L+=[i]*c
if L[0]<3:L=L[:0:-1]
T='SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY'
print''.join(T[[p for p in range(3,104)if all(p%k for k in range(2,p))].index(q)]for q in L)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RcxLU8IwFAXgfX5FNkwTeZi0CGPkLlR8oFFR6zOTBVMLXulcQgdGV/712rJxec535lQESGG7EZIhaGbBefb9iUX@2yXDOLZBH2WgGN@VnFo40iZrWtoHrAdznhnbBod@L2N1sk75UWIsWGeU6WrPUogepzfn9v5p8np7@nL3cHzxnp5dXT6PT67fIhZKpE0U9b5WSCJ1LvD5quSBI/FyRotcJB2t@rK@nhWFCK3lzpf/HneClL6H9JH/iLX0Da8btrKq4sFADQ8S3Y8Tdaj/AA)

Answer (score 8):

## Bash + GNU utilities + bsd-games package, 170

Seems pretty non-optimal, but it works:

```bash
p='printf %03d\n'
a=(`factor $1`)
x=$[a[1]<3]
$p `primes 3 104`|paste - <(fold -1<<<SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY)|join -o1.2 - <($p ${a[@]:x+1})|(((x))&&tac||cat)|tr -d \\n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#RZHbjhMxDIbv@xTWqrvbERrkU5wEWsT5fD5DW6mj6VS7CDpVZy4qMTx7MSsQyUWi2P/vz86m3UPfdH1ddQ1cbkE0RQVNwkFBgkRm0KyCDJLRCExjBkNlgqBk5rmZSF3EgTArAwtKcnVSZReQoSX0kwgxBQhMnD3dYsqMapBSkGyU3TYqEkoEjtGYogCxuA0GNBBBDc5lyb3EOJIiBr9Gh7OcnDYJIXFCc2bkEMh3MidQE2FNFATclyI7GrPXUacgdkJI5tAYk5cBNsMYhNRbyXQT1u0IfHVND2UJ43/zunrc7S@3/QZOTjsob8HJ/@hxNzv/GzxFWS@256NqNlltqrr3mY9pVYwOs/G8mtNyKsvReAcrT//RdOBto66GXdX1DZQwnWza72soaTqdvnv94uHzNx@efH5579Ort3cefX3/4Onjj/fvPvtSDN9a/7@ypet8JXLD8c9qfnt543CNfhXDZDI5FMXZWV/Vw1BXfTH0eyjXsFhsj38aaeqLdrRut83xNw).

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

49 bytes of code, +1 for the `-P` flag.

```
%2?Uk :Uk Åw)£`yspmflquixncÙgz’jhvdbk`g#ho fj bX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@69qZB@arWAFxIdbyzUPLU6oLC7ITcspLM2syEs@PFM4verQpKyMspSk7IR05Yx8hbQshaSI//@NzMwMzE2NDU2MjA0sDRV0AwA)

This could be way shorter if only Japt had a couple more features...

#### Explanation

`` `yspmflquixncÙgz’jhvdbk` `` is just the same string everyone else is using compressed as much as Japt can compress it (3 bytes shorter than the original!). Japt's only built-in compression tool at the moment replaces common pairs of lowercase letter with a single-byte char.

So let's examine the actual code:

```
%2?Uk :Uk Å  w)
%2?Uk :Uk s1 w)
%2?             // If the input mod 2 is non-zero,
   Uk           //   take the prime factors of the input (U).
      :Uk       // Otherwise, take the prime factors of the input,
          s1 w  //   slice off the first one (2), and reverse.
```

Then `£` is used to replace each item `X` in the result like this:

```
"string"g#h o fj bX
"string"g104o fj bX

         104o         // Create the range [0...104).
              fj      // Filter to only items Z where Z.j() is truthy (Z is prime).
                      // This results in the list of prime numbers from 2 to 103.
                 bX   // Take the index of X in this list.
"string"g             // Get the char in the compressed string at that index.
                      // For `y`, the index is 26, but since the string is only 26 chars
                      // long, Japt wraps around and grabs the first char in the string.
```

The result is an array of characters at this point, so the `-P` flag joins it into a single string, and the result is implicitly sent to output.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆfÆCUṖ$¹e@?1’ị“¡3ḅḲ+Ṿɼ¡ẏƙẊƘ’œ?ØA¤
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AU0Asv//w4Zmw4ZDVeG5liTCuWVAPzHigJnhu4vigJzCoTPhuIXhuLIr4bm@ybzCoeG6j8aZ4bqKxpjigJnFkz/DmEHCpP///zg4NTM5NjE5OQ)**

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>54</s> 47 bytes

7 bytes thanks to isaacg

```
s__W%Q2@L."AZ❤O❤❤❤❤❤❤Q❤9❤❤×❤❤"xL_MP#r_3_103-PQ2
```

(`❤` represents an unprintable character)

Pyth doesn't have many prime built-ins...

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 73 5f 5f 57 25 51 32 40 4c 2e 22 41 5a 03 4f f3 s__W%Q2@L."AZ.O.
0000010: 14 af 15 ed f5 51 90 39 d5 18 d7 20 a8 22 78 4c .....Q.9... ."xL
0000020: 5f 4d 50 23 72 5f 33 5f 31 30 33 2d 50 51 32    _MP#r_3_103-PQ2
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s__W%25Q2%40L.%22AZ%03O%C3%B3%14%C2%AF%15%C3%AD%C3%B5Q%C2%909%C3%95%18%C3%97%C2%A0%C2%A8%22xL_MP%23r_3_103-PQ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=34874%0A483254%0A353722%0A494302%0A39061%0A6479%0A60421%0A48911474%0A2510942%0A2303854%0A844261%0A1606801%0A1110085%0A5212974%0A67892046%0A885396199%0A67401037%0A1238440506%0A33045832681%0A1362714005%0A137302698%0A358310128062%0A40255151586%0A164633248153%0A621172442227%0A2467812606%0A86385078330%0A26607531423091&debug=0)

Comment: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%22AZ%03O%C3%B3%14%C2%AF%15%C3%AD%C3%B5Q%C2%909%C3%95%18%C3%97%C2%A0%C2%A8%22&debug=0

Comment: @isaacg I tried it, and I don't know why it produces strange result for the last one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s__W%25Q2%40L.%22AZ%03O%C3%B3%14%C2%AF%15%C3%AD%C3%B5Q%C2%909%C3%95%18%C3%97%C2%A0%C2%A8%22xL_MP%23r_3_103-PQ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=34874%0A483254%0A353722%0A494302%0A39061%0A6479%0A60421%0A48911474%0A2510942%0A2303854%0A844261%0A1606801%0A1110085%0A5212974%0A67892046%0A885396199%0A67401037%0A1238440506%0A33045832681%0A1362714005%0A137302698%0A358310128062%0A40255151586%0A164633248153%0A621172442227%0A2467812606%0A86385078330%0A26607531423091&debug=0

Comment: @isaacg That's very weird.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 40 bytes

```
Æfḟ2ÆCṚ⁸Ḃ¤¡Ṛị“YSPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4Le3hjvlGh9ucH@6c9ahxx8MdTYeWHFoI5Dzc3f2oYU5kcICvm09gqGeEn3O4f5Cje1SIq5dHmIuT9////82NTE0tjAA)

[Verify all testcases at once!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#DY85TgNhDIV7zuLCu/2XEPZ9CUtAtJwjpAgFN0AghETJAQbRJSeZuchgubAtvef3eVwvn/ruk9fLSf/7Njx3fbdYfa@@aun/Xof5@@zq/GT3@OL64O50cnt2ubl3P9053L/Z3joa5h8b65dh8TMbx/FBNENBU9gUxCSYQZsKMkhDJ3CNBo7KVKpGpCVnI2zKwIKS5UtVLik5emJ1IsQ0MCZuJffIxqgOmSbNqdXBUCSUAGIpNxo6iKBagXjWCXEOUkSrMYrGWxZeCiFxohckshlVpVewughrkgk4EwUXEXMAa4UTFxikFytGVgywO4YJaX3Q6PEf) (slightly modified)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 59 bytes

```
'SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY'{~(p:>:i.26)i.[:|.@}.^:(2={.)q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#JZDJakJRDIb3PkXoRi/IbaaTk3OKpfM8zwMUiii6aovdqX11G5AskkD@P1@y0fa640Ht9pcVoQI2q@79zeXRxe3j6cvV/vP13e7x28Ph2cnTwd75a3f@1/uu23XasjXT9r0u2p1l@1F7PJi3zU9dNZ3f0ex3BoMKiwr9ClubIOpZQV04KUiSzAxaVJBBChqBaS5gqEyQlMxithBpiDgRFmVgQfFQuyqHgAzNMTIRoidITFxi3LIXRjVwT1KMSthmRULJwDkbUxYglrDBhAYiqCm4zMNLjDMpYooyB5wVD1oXQmJHC2bklCjCLQjURFidkkD4UuZAY449GhTEQQhuAY3ZYw2wGeYkpHFKoc5oOPmC9av6LYxh9DmcrPvVPw)

Quite simple...

```
'SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY'{~(p:>:i.26)i.[:|.@}.^:(2={.)q:
                              (p:>:i.26)                      first 26 primes after 2
                                        i.                    for which the indices is
                                                         q:   prime factors
                                            |.@}.             remove first and reverse
                                                 ^:           if
                                                   (2={.)     the first entry is 2
                            {~                                reverse index
'..........................'                                  hardcoded string
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 173 Bytes

```
for($i=2;1<$n=&$argn;$n%$i?++$i:$r[]=$i.!$n/=$i)for($t=$i;$i>2&!$w[$i]&&$i%--$t;$t>2?:$w[$i]=SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY[$p++]);$r[0]>2?:rsort($r);foreach($r as$s)echo$w[$s];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5bd12c1943f66d4a93056d55eabb1c0e497da3d3)

Expanded

```
for($i=2;1<$n=&$argn; # loop till input is 1
$n%$i?++$i:$r[]=$i.!$n/=$i) #after loop add value to result if input is divisible and divide input
  for($t=$i;$i>2&!$w[$i]&&$i%--$t; # loop if number is gt 2 and not in letter array till number is divisible 
  $t>2?:$w[$i]=SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY[$p++]) # if is prime add to letter array
  ; # make nothing in the loop
$r[0]>2?:rsort($r); # reverse result array if 2 is in result array
foreach($r as$s) # loop result array
  echo$w[$s]; # Output
```

## PHP, 178 Bytes

```
for($z=2;$p<26;$t>1?:$w[$z]=SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY[$p++])for($t=++$z;$z%--$t;);for($i=2;1<$n=&$argn;)$n%$i?++$i:$r[]=$i.!$n/=$i;$r[0]>2?:rsort($r);foreach($r as$s)echo$w[$s];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f50b5f6f427a7228178d0f3e00d3d77ae50585d0)

Expanded

```
for($z=2;$p<26;
$t>1?:$w[$z]=SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY[$p++]) # after loop if is prime add to letter array
  for($t=++$z;$z%--$t;); 
for($i=2;1<$n=&$argn;)  # loop till input is 1
  $n%$i?++$i:$r[]=$i.!$n/=$i; #add value to result if input is divisible and divide input
$r[0]>2?:rsort($r); # reverse result array if 2 is in result array
foreach($r as$s) # loop result array
  echo$w[$s]; # Output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 27 bytes

```
∆Ǐḣ«
‹ṀnΠ⌈≈Ǐ¶¨≤½꘍Qr←«f*∑$ßṘ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oiGx4/huKPCq1xu4oC54bmAbs6g4oyI4omIx4/CtsKo4omkwr3qmI1RcuKGkMKrZiriiJEkw5/huZgiLCIiLCIyNjYwNzUzMTQyMzA5MVxuMzU4MzEwMTI4MDYyXG4xNjA2ODAxIl0=) Port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117830/100664).

```
∆Ǐ             # Exponents of prime factors
  ḣ            # Remove the first item and leave it on the stack
   «...«f      # Compressed string "spmflquixncworagztejhvdbky", as a char list
         *∑    # Repeat each character by its corresponding exponent, and concatenate
           $ß  # If the popped item is nonzero (i.e. factor of 2)
             Ṙ # Then reverse the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 1420 bytes

```python
lambda x:(lambda a,b,e,k,l,m,q,p:len.__name__[:a].join(dict(zip((lambda n:(lambda n,f,g:f(n,e,[],f,g))(n,lambda n,i,r,f,g:g(n,i+b,r,f,g)if i<n else r,lambda n,i,r,f,g:f(n,i,[r,r+[i]][all(i%x!=a for x in[e]+r)],f,g)))(l*e*(k*l+b)),(lambda n,o,t:(lambda n,f,g:f(n, len.__name__[:a],f,g))(n,lambda n,s,f,g:g(n,s,f,g)if n>o else s,lambda n,s,f,g:f(n//t,s+chr(n%t),f,g)))((((((k<<e)-b)<<m)+m)<<((k<<q)+(k<<b)))+(((((k<<e)-b)<<e)+b)<<((k<<q)-(b<<b)))+((((((b<<k)+b))<<l)+b)<<((((k<<e)-b)<<l)+(b<<b)))+(((((k<<e)-b)<<l)-k)<<((m<<m)+p))-(((p<<m)-b)<<((m<<m)-(b<<b)))+(((m<<k)+b)<<((((m<<e)-b)<<k)-(b<<b)))+(((((k<<e)-b)<<l)-m)<<((((b<<l)+b)<<k)+k))-(((((b<<l)-b)<<l)-p)<<((b<<p)+(b<<b)))-(((p<<k)-b)<<((((b<<l)-b)<<k)+k))-(((k<<q)-b)<<((p<<l)))+(((m<<m)+m)<<((((k<<e)+b)<<k)-b))-(((k<<m)+b)<<((k<<m)-b))-(((m<<m)+k)<<((((k<<e)-b)<<k)-(b<<b)))+(((((k<<e)+b)<<e)+b)<<((m<<l)-(b<<e)))-(((((k<<e)+b)<<e)+b)<<((((b<<l)+b)<<e)-b))+((((((b<<k)+b))<<k)+b)<<((p<<k)))+(((((k<<e)-b)<<k)-k)<<((k<<l)))+(((m<<l)+b)<<((m<<k)))+(((m<<e)-b)<<((b<<m)+(b<<b)))+((((((b<<k)+b))<<e)-b)<<((k<<k)+b))+(((m<<k)-b)<<((b<<l)+b))-((((k<<e)-b))<<((k<<e)))+(((m<<e)+b)<<e)-b,b,b<<l*e)))[i]for i in(lambda x: [x.remove(e), x[::-b]][b] if e in x else x)((lambda x:(lambda x,g,h:g(x,b,[],g,h))(x,lambda x,n,r,g,h:h(x,n+b,r,g,h)if x>b else r,lambda x,n,r,g,h:h(x//n,n,r+[n],g,h)if x%n==a else g(x,n,r,g,h)))(x))))(*[x for x in range(True<<len(len.__name__))])
```

This could definitely by shorted some, but it's my attempt at solving it with no numbers or string literals. I realize this is a code-golf problem and this isn't *exactly* short but wanted to share anyway, not sure if this breaks any rules or not.

Was a lot of fun to make, I used the algorithm on [this blog post](https://benkurtovic.com/2014/06/01/obfuscating-hello-world.html) to reduce the ASCII numerical representation of "SPMFLQUIXNCWORAGZTEJHVDBKY" in to the bit-shift expression I use. I also generally took a lot of inspiration from this blog, I wanted to try it out myself and this seemed like a good challenge to do it with.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b02774144c02ff410e7c4cf21b6ca5a6) is a slightly more readable version, with some more sensible variable names too

Comment: There's at least one space that can be removed.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a code golf competition, so your objective should be to make your code as short as possible. Our [help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states that *all solutions to challenges should [...] be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. [...] An entry to a code golf contest needs to be golfed*